# Android receive GCM while display is off

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM to send some data from my server to my app.
The messaging is working fine. I receive every massage instantly on my device.
However, The problem is: It does not work when the display of my smartphone is off.
Maybe it has s.th. to do with my smartphone? I'm running Android 5 and notification from other apps work fine (like whatsapp).

server data:

```
{ 
 "data": {
 "id": "5", 
 "message": "test"
},
"registration_ids": ["myRegId"],
 "priority": "high"
}
```

Manifest:

```
...
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".GcmMessageHandler"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.asdf.myapp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.asdf.myapp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Receiver:

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        Log.d("test", "message received");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed, that the issue only occurs if I'm connected to my WLAN.
When WLAN is disabled, I get the GCM message no matter what.
I've read this reddit post and followed its instructions which seemed to solve my issues.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2z1gyo/fix_lollipop_wifi_issues_and_coincidentally_the/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `receiver` class should extend from WakefulBroadcastReceiver to guaranteeing that the CPU is awake so that your listener service can complete its task even if your device is lock.

**Manifest**

```
<permission
    android:name="com.oostaa.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.oostaa.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver
   android:name=".receiver.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
   android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
         <category android:name="com.oostaa.app" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note: com.oostaa.app is my package name.

**Receiver:**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
       startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
       setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
   }
}
```